# Probability of drawing a card from suit giving n cards already drawn and some of them unknown

Tags: probability, poker

Say you have 15 cards already drawn, of which you  know five and four of these five are of the same suit, what is the probability of drawing a card of the same suit as of the four from the remaining 37 cards?

Any references or solution roadmap are appreciated.

Comment: Why do the 15 cards matter if you don't know what they are?

Comment: Imagine the 10 previously drawn, but unknown, cards are on the bottom of the deck. They will have the same effect on the suit of the top card in the deck as they would if they are in players' hands.

Answer (score 1):

Any card you pick could be one of $9$ of the same suit out of $47$ unknown cards. The other $10$ cards are a red herring inserted to confuse the student.

$$P = \frac{9}{47}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume you know 9 cards so 43 are left.  There are still 9 of the suite. So 9/43.

Answer (score 1):

We don't  know the remaining 10 cards so we can assume we have 47 cards to drawn from and we have nine cards of that suit so

P(A) =9/47